# Mocking WebSocket in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a library that uses WebSockets. I'm trying to mock the websocket using the code below. The library `ROSController` uses web sockets, but I keep getting the `WebSocket is not defined.`

```
import { ROSController }  from '../ROSController.jsx';
var socketMock;
var windowMock;
var address = 'ws://test.address';

beforeAll(function() {
    var WebSocket = jasmine.createSpy();
    WebSocket.and.callFake(function (url) {
      socketMock = {
        url: url,
        readyState: WebSocket.CONNECTING,
        send: jasmine.createSpy(),
        close: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSING;
        }),

        // methods to mock the internal behaviour of the real WebSocket
        _open: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.OPEN;
          socketMock.onopen && socketMock.onopen();
        },
        _message: function (msg) {
          socketMock.onmessage && socketMock.onmessage({data: msg});
        },
        _error: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED;
          socketMock.onerror && socketMock.onerror();
        },
        _close: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED;
          socketMock.onclose && socketMock.onclose();
        }
      };
      return socketMock;
    });
    WebSocket.CONNECTING = 0;
    WebSocket.OPEN = 1;
    WebSocket.CLOSING = 2;
    WebSocket.CLOSED = 3;
    windowMock = {
      WebSocket: WebSocket
    };

    return WebSocket;
});

test('the subscription JSON produced is correct', () => {
    console.log(WebSocket); //<----- It fails here
    JSON.parse((new ROSController('')).callService('/test','', function(){}));

});
```

Comment: where is `jasmine` declared?

Comment: In my package.json? I just run Jest at the root of the project. This is in the scripts/__tests__ folder. Jest seems to run fine, I just can't pick up the WebSocket variable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In jest, you need to add stuff that should be available in the global scope aka `window`, to the `global` namespace:

```
global.WebSocket= WebSocket
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I've added WebSocket to the global scope both in the test setup and the unit test. In both cases I get a `ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined`

Answer (score 17):

Use `mock-socket` package and then `global` to make it available for nodejs:

```
import { WebSocket } from 'mock-socket';

global.WebSocket = WebSocket;
```

Comment: I've used `mock-socket` before and I would urge folks to avoid it. It's not really maintained and has a variety of bugs (many of which have been there for many years). I haven't found a better alternative to writing your own mock implementation but every time I've had to its taken less time than working around the issues in `mock-socket`

Comment: mock-socket is popular: 500k weekly downloads. It also works well for me. Maybe Mattia's comment isn't relevant anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I created a file `__mocks__/ws.js`:

```js
const {WebSocket} = require("mock-socket");

module.exports = WebSocket
```

See note from [jest-websocket-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-websocket-mock#using-jest-websocket-mock-to-interact-with-a-non-global-websocket-object):

> // **mocks**/ws.js
>
> export { WebSocket as default } from "mock-socket";

And [the manual-mocks docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks):

> the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory ... and will be **automatically** mocked.